# WordPress plugin overwrites other plugin's archive-*.php

Tags: wordpress, templates

I'm working for a tire company and I'm writing two plugins.

The first plugin is to show alloy wheels.
The second plugin is to show tires.

Both plugins come as a custom post type 'wheels' and 'tires', and both plugins have a template logic in it (templates/archive-wheels.php and templates/archive-tires.php)

**My problem:**
When both plugins are active, the **wheels** plugin overwrites the **tires** archive page and I don't know why on earth it is doing it.

I have really tried to avoid namespace conflicts in advance by using other function names, other prefixes etc.

Here is the relevant code for registering the CPTs and the template logic for both plugins:

Register Custom Post Type **wheels**:

```
function rg_wp_wheels_register_cpt(){

    // Custom Post Type Name
    $cpt_name = 'wheels';
    // CPT Features
    $cpt_features = array(
        'title',
        'revisions'
    );
    // Slug for archive page
    $cpt_slug = 'designs';
    $labels = array(
        'name'                      =>  __('Wheels', 'rg-wp-wheels'),
        'singular_name'             =>  __('Wheel', 'rg-wp-wheels'),
        'menu_name'                 =>  __('Wheels', 'rg-wp-wheels'),
        'name_admin_bar'            =>  __('Wheel', 'rg-wp-wheels'),
        'all_items'                 =>  __('Designs', 'rg-wp-wheels'),
        'add_name'                  =>  __('Add new wheel', 'rg-wp-wheels'),
        'add_new_item'              =>  __('Add new wheel', 'rg-wp-wheels'),
        'edit'                      =>  __('Edit wheel', 'rg-wp-wheels'),
        'edit_item'                 =>  __('Edit wheel', 'rg-wp-wheels'),
        'new_item'                  =>  __('New wheel', 'rg-wp-wheels'),
        'view'                      =>  __('View', 'rg-wp-wheels'),
        'view_item'                 =>  __('View', 'rg-wp-wheels'),
        'search_items'              =>  __('Search ', 'rg-wp-wheels'),
        'parent'                    =>  __('Parent', 'rg-wp-wheels'),
        'not_found'                 =>  __('No wheels found', 'rg-wp-wheels'),
        'not_found_in_trash'        =>  __('No wheels found in Trash', 'rg-wp-wheels')
);
    $args = array(
        'labels'                =>  $labels,
        'public'                =>  true,
        'publicly_queryable'    =>  true,
        'exclude_from_search'   =>  false,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     =>  true,
        'show_ui'               =>  true,
        'show_in_menu'          =>  true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     =>  true,
        'menu_position'         =>  21,
        'menu_icon'             =>  'dashicons-marker',
        'can_export'            =>  true,
        'delete_with_user'      =>  false,
        'hierarchical'          =>  false,
        'has_archive'           =>  true,
        'query_var'             =>  true,
        'capability_type'       =>  'post',
        'map_meta_cap'          =>  true,
    // 'capabilities'       => array(),
        'rewrite'               =>  array(
            'slug'      => $cpt_slug,
            'with_front'=> true,
            'pages'     => true,
            'feeds'     => false
        ),
        'supports'      => $cpt_features
    );
    register_post_type($cpt_name, $args);
}
add_action('init', 'rg_wp_wheels_register_cpt');
```

Template Logic for the **wheels** plugin

```
function rg_wp_wheels_template_logic($original_template) {
    $post_type = get_post_type();

    if(is_archive() || is_search() && $post_type == 'wheels') {

        if(file_exists(get_template_directory_uri() . '/archive-wheels.php')) {
            return get_template_directory_uri() . '/archive-wheels.php';
        } else {
            return plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'templates/archive-wheels.php';
        }

    } elseif(is_single() && $post_type == 'wheels') {

        if(file_exists(get_template_directory_uri() . '/single-wheels.php')) {
            return get_template_directory_uri() . '/single-wheels.php';
        } else {
            return plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'templates/single-wheels.php';
        }

    }

    return $original_template;
    }
    add_action('template_include', 'rg_wp_wheels_template_logic');
```

Register Custom Post Type **tires**:

```
function rg_wp_tires_register_cpt(){

    // Custom Post Type Name
    $cpt_name = 'tires';
    // CPT Features
    $cpt_features = array(
        'title',
        'revisions'
    );
    // Slug
    $cpt_slug_tires = 'profiles';
    $labels = array(
        'name'                      =>  __('Tires', 'rg-wp-tires'),
        'singular_name'             =>  __('Tire', 'rg-wp-tires'),
        'menu_name'                 =>  __('Tires', 'rg-wp-tires'),
        'name_admin_bar'            =>  __('Tires', 'rg-wp-tires'),
        'all_items'                 =>  __('Profiles', 'rg-wp-tires'),
        'add_name'                  =>  __('Add new tire', 'rg-wp-tires'),
        'add_new_item'              =>  __('Add new tire', 'rg-wp-tires'),
        'edit'                      =>  __('Edit tire', 'rg-wp-tires'),
        'edit_item'                 =>  __('Edit tire', 'rg-wp-tires'),
        'new_item'                  =>  __('New tire', 'rg-wp-tires'),
        'view'                      =>  __('View', 'rg-wp-tires'),
        'view_item'                 =>  __('View', 'rg-wp-tires'),
        'search_items'              =>  __('Search ', 'rg-wp-tires'),
        'parent'                    =>  __('Parent', 'rg-wp-tires'),
        'not_found'                 =>  __('No tires found', 'rg-wp-tires'),
        'not_found_in_trash'        =>  __('No tires found in Trash', 'rg-wp-tires')
);

    $args = array(
        'labels'                =>  $labels,
        'public'                =>  true,
        'publicly_queryable'    =>  true,
        'exclude_from_search'   =>  false,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     =>  true,
        'show_ui'               =>  true,
        'show_in_menu'          =>  true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     =>  true,
        'menu_position'         =>  22,
        'menu_icon'             =>  'dashicons-marker',
        'can_export'            =>  true,
        'delete_with_user'      =>  false,
        'hierarchical'          =>  false,
        'has_archive'           =>  true,
        'query_var'             =>  true,
        'capability_type'       =>  'post',
        'map_meta_cap'          =>  true,
        // 'capabilities'       => array(),
        'rewrite'               =>  array(
            'slug'      => $cpt_slug_tires,
            'with_front'=> true,
            'pages'     => true,
            'feeds'     => false
        ),
        'supports'      => $cpt_features
    );
    register_post_type($cpt_name, $args);
}
add_action('init', 'rg_wp_tires_register_cpt');
```

Template logic for the **tires** plugin:

```
function rg_wp_tires_template_logic($original_template) {
$post_type = get_post_type();

if(is_archive() || is_search() && $post_type == 'tires') {

    if(file_exists(get_template_directory_uri() . '/archive-tires.php')) {
        return get_template_directory_uri() . '/archive-tires.php';
    } else {
        return plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'templates/archive-tires.php';
    }

} elseif(is_single() && $post_type == 'tires') {

    if(file_exists(get_template_directory_uri() . '/single-tires.php')) {
        return get_template_directory_uri() . '/single-tires.php';
    } else {
        return plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'templates/single-tires.php';
    }

}

return $original_template;
}
add_action('template_include', 'rg_wp_tires_template_logic');
```

**When I deactivate the wheels plugin, the tire plugin template logic works perfectly fine. When both plugins are active, the archive-wheels.php ALWAYS overwrites the archive-tires.php. Why?**

Please help me, I'm losing my mind on this.

Comment: I would post this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/. It all looks good to me, very strange.

Comment: Thank you Christina, I've cracked the nut with the help of a core developer. And yes, I've already posted this question on the WPSE forum, but nobody answered.. so I've tried my luck here.. the fist conditional was the error, please see my answer below. Thank you for trying to help out :)

Answer (score 1):

A core contributor had merci with me and an answer.

The problem is this conditional statement:

```
if(is_archive() || is_search() && $post_type == 'wheels') {....
```

which needs to be wrapped in two additional brackets with archive and search

```
if((is_archive() || is_search()) && $post_type == 'wheels') {....
```

Notice that the archive and search are wrapped up in additional brackets

On top, get_post_type is NOT correct in this case. It should use: is_post_type_archive('CPT')..

```
if( is_post_type_archive('wheels') || (is_search() && $_GET['post_type'] === 'wheels')) {...
```

The final correct function looks like this:

```
// Template Logik
function rg_wp_tires_template_logic($original_template) {

    if(is_post_type_archive('tires') || (is_search() && $_GET['post_type'] === 'tires')) {

        if(file_exists(get_template_directory_uri() . '/archive-tires.php')) {
            return get_template_directory_uri() . '/archive-tires.php';
        } else {
            return plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'templates/archive-tires.php';
        }

    } elseif(is_singular('tires')) {

        if(file_exists(get_template_directory_uri() . '/single-tires.php')) {
            return get_template_directory_uri() . '/single-tires.php';
        } else {
            return plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'templates/single-tires.php';
        }

    }

    return $original_template;
}
add_action('template_include', 'rg_wp_tires_template_logic');
```

Comment: Great! Very hard to see. WordPress has code writing guidelines, one of which is a space  like this: ``if( is_post_type_archive( 'tires' ) || ( is_search() && $_GET[ 'post_type' ] === 'tires' ) ) {`` -- easier to read.